# Adding a minus sign before pd.get_dummies return 255 instead of -1

Tags: python, pandas

<s>I think this is a bug, so not strictly on-topic on this site, but I'd like the help of the pandas' community here with it.</s> Let's consider this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,1,1,0,1], 'col2':list('aabbc')})
```

If I use `pd.get_dummies` on the second column with a minus sign in front, here is what I get:

```
print (-pd.get_dummies(df.col2))
     a    b    c
0  255    0    0
1  255    0    0
2    0  255    0
3    0  255    0
4    0    0  255
```

While the expected result can be obtained using `str.get_dummies()`:

```
print (-df.col2.str.get_dummies())
   a  b  c
0 -1  0  0
1 -1  0  0
2  0 -1  0
3  0 -1  0
4  0  0 -1
```

I have `python 3.7.1`, one of the latest version of pandas `pd.__version__ == "0.24.2"` and run on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want

```
(-pd.get_dummies(df.col2, dtype=int))
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0 -1  0  0
1 -1  0  0
2  0 -1  0
3  0 -1  0
4  0  0 -1
```

since the default `dtype` for `pd.get_dummies` is 8-bit unsigned int (`dtype : dtype, default np.uint8`)?

Comment: I guessed from your question and verified by looking at the source code / doc.